# C++ Builder 2009 - IndySystem120.bpl - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++builder, indy, c++builder-2009

I'm using `C++ Builder 2009`. I have the indy system, core and protocol installed in my environment. Recently, about once a week I get a message of:

Title: `bds.exe - Entry Point Not Found`

Message: `The procedure entry point @Idstack@TIdStack@Make$qqrv could not be located in the dynamic link library IndySystem120.bpl`

The solution I've been doing is closing the current project. Rebuild/reinstall the 3 indy projects (core, system, protocol) then everything works fine for about a week.

The troubleshooting steps I've tried so far was searching my system for bpl files related to the Indy system and removing them before doing a clean install (in case there was some sort of pathing issue). I then ran Builder as administrator and installed the components. I thought I solve the problem, but alas I'm having the issue again. Does anyone have thoughts on anything else I can try to solve this more permanently?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade your C++Builder 2009's copy of Indy?

Comment: I have my environment in a win 7 VM. XE has not been on the VM for sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using the same version of Indy I was using previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had the problem for a couple of weeks and had to do several rebuilds of the library. I run the environment through a VM and found that my VM was low on space. I found that by clearing up some space on the drive that the problem went away. I've been working in the environment for over a month now without having to rebuild, where I used to have to do it 1 to 2 times a week.

Answer (score 1):

The `TIdStack.Make()` method was removed in Indy 10.5.7 for the RAD Studio XE release.  If you have upgraded your installation of Indy 10 and have newer package versions floating around your system, that can interfere with any packages that were compiled to use the original Indy packages that shipped with C++Builder 2009.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No XE on the machine. I posted what the core problem was below in an answer.